# "lends credence to...'

Tags: phrase-requests

The expression "lends credence to the conjecture" is standard. I was wondering if it sounds hyperformal or affected and can be replaced by
"provides evidence as to the validity of the conjecture",
"provides evidence for the validity of the conjecture",
or "improves the confidence in the conjecture".

Comment: *X lends credence to the conjecture* = *X **supports** the conjecture.* A weaker assertion than ***validates, proves***.

Comment: Yes, but "provides evidence as to the validity" is definitely weaker than "validate" or "prove", as "evidence" implies some degree of uncertainty.

Comment: You keep mentioning ***evidence*** (in principle, ***definitive*** confirmation of a hypothesis), but a relatively weak assertion about ***lending credence*** wouldn't usually be used in contexts where there's actual "evidence" involved. Even ***credence*** itself (weakly ***lent***, more forcefully, ***conferred***) is just about being "credible" (***can't rule it out,*** not ***must believe it***).

Answer (score 1):

Hyper formal or affected language is determined by your audience. Some groups won't mind "lends credence to the conjecture" others will be repelled by it.

Here's one persons thoughts on how to Tailor Your Writing to Your Audience
https://www.writeraccess.com/blog/tailoring-your-writing-to-your-audience/

FumbleFingers has suggested some alternatives - supports, validates, proves